# maxima: solving a set of equations

Tags: math, maxima

I'm trying to solve a set of symbolic equations in maxima.

I'm using "algsys" comand, and it works, but the answer is depended on "%r1".

I dont understand what %r1 is, and how can I get a explicit expression?

maxima code:

```
(%i4) eq1:diff(diff(Lag,diff(u(t),t)),t)-diff(Lag,u(t)),ratsimp;

(%i5) eq2:diff(diff(Lag,diff(v(t),t)),t)-diff(Lag,v(t)),ratsimp;

(%i6) eq3:diff(diff(Lag,diff(theta(t),t)),t)-diff(Lag,theta(t))-Tm,ratsimp;

(%i7) A:algsys([eq1, eq2, eq3], [diff(u(t),t,2),diff(v(t),t,2),diff(theta(t),t,2)]);
```

PS: cant post picture cause it's my first question...

Comment: well, dont know if it's any thing I did, but I restarted maxima and it works...

Answer (score 1):

FWIW %r1 is simply names for roots introduced by `solve` and `algsys`.

See http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_20.html